# Use Particular Version of ui-bootstrap in my directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an AngularJS directive and I use ui-bootstrap version 0.4.0 in my site.  But for this particular directive I need to use features of 0.6.0 is there a way to use version 0.6.0 just for this directive?  I cannot update the entire site to use 0.6.0 because there are features in 0.4.0 that I need and do not have the time to update the code to use the 0.6.0 equivalent.

Comment: By defining two different modules, I think , you can do it. One module having .4 version and second .6 version. Still not completely sure.

Comment: If it is a different html page then yes otherwise no

Comment: You would have to go through renaming modules, templates, directives, services modules etc to avoid namespace collision